# context menu goes below the pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I need a context menu and I'm trying to set its position close the pointer click. Its position is fixed.

```
<ul id='cmenu'>
    <li class='citem' id='c-edit'>EDIT</li>
    <li class='citem' id='c-public'>PUBLIC</li>
    <li class='citem' id='c-later'>PUBLIC LATER</li>
</ul>
```

**js**

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', '.itemp', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var w = $('#cmenu').width();
    var h = $('#cmenu').height();
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var cx = window.innerWidth/2;
    var cy = window.innerHeight/2;
    var topb = y-h;
    if (x <= cx) {$('#cmenu').css('left', x + 10 + 'px');}
    else {$('#cmenu').css('left', x-w + 'px');}
    if (y <= cy) {$('#cmenu').css('top', y + 'px');}
    else {$('#cmenu').css('top', topb + 'px');}
    $('#cmenu').show();
});
```

Horizontal position is always ok, but vertical is sometimes ok - sometimes about 50 - 70 px below the pointer. I can't see a reason. Clearing cache doesn't help.

Comment: Seems ok to me (https://jsfiddle.net/tbqwkpgg/). Can you try to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you may use [jQuery-contextMenu plugin](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/):

```js
$.contextMenu({
    // define which elements trigger this menu
    selector: ".itemp",
    // define the elements of the menu
    items: {
        edit: {
            name: "EDIT", callback: function (key, opt) {
                console.log("EDIT!");
            }
        },
        public: {
            name: "PUBLIC", callback: function (key, opt) {
                console.log("PUBLIC!")
            }
        },
        public_later: {
            name: "PUBLIC LATER", callback: function (key, opt) {
                console.log("PUBLIC LATER!")
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>

<div class="itemp">This is a sample div element: rigth mouse click to open context menu</div>
<br/>
<div>Here there is no context menu</div>
```